# arrange chat message in sequence

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working with CodeIgniter and MySQL. I want to create chat system. So, I want to display message in sequence like sender message than receiver message and continue follow this system.

Here, my database looks like this :
[image]

For example, use id as 1 and 2.

As shown in image, in **from** column 1 user_id send message to 2 user_id in to column and 2 user_id send message to 1 user_id.

So I want to arrange message as per the time. So what query and functionality required?

I want to display chat as shown in below image :
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the expected output based the data given?

Comment: @1000111 I have added image as I want output.

Comment: @1000111 be careful for what ya ask for :p

Comment: Being careful from now on B) @Drew

Comment: you just simply select data by descending order it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ex. you want to get chat of user id 1 and 2 then,
Try this

```
select * from messages where (from = 1 OR from = 2) AND (to = 1 OR to = 2) order by time desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run simply select query then its retrieve data in sequence coz you are storing data into the sequence then whats the actual problem?

Comment: I need to retrieve message of two person as chat on skype.

Comment: You can use something like that:SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (user_id1,user_id2,...);